# How do I find which data records weren't found for in SQL?

Tags: php, sql

I'm doing a search that tries to look for contacts with specified company names and job titles as the WHERE parameters. Sometimes there will not be any contacts with the specified job title and company. As I am using sets of company names how can I find out which results weren't found? This is really hard to explain...

An example SQL statement might be

```
SELECT *
  FROM contacts
 WHERE company_name IN ('bbc', 'yahoo', 'some company')
   AND contact_position
  LIKE 'manager'
```

I want to know which companies did not have any contacts for that job title, if that makes sense?

I have made this so far, but I presume there is a much better way of doing this:

```
$contacts_no_inv = Contact::find_query("
    SELECT * 
      FROM contacts
     WHERE {$data_search}
       AND contact_position
      LIKE '%{$_POST['job_title']}%'
");

if ($contacts_no_inv) {
    foreach ($contacts_no_inv as $contact_no_inv) {
         $companies_found[] = $contact_no_inv->company_name;
         if (!in_array($contact_no_inv->contact_id, $idArr)) {
             $filtered_no_inv[] = $contact_no_inv;
         }
    }
}

$companies_found = array_unique($companies_found);
$companies_found = array_filter($companies_found);

foreach ($_POST['query'] as $query) {
     if (!in_array(strtolower($query), array_map('strtolower', $companies_found))) {
         if (count(explode(' ', strtolower($query))) > 1) {
             foreach (explode(' ', $query) as $query_element) {
                 if (!in_array(strtolower($query_element), array_map('strtolower', $companies_found))) {
                     $companies_found[] = $query;
                 }
             }
         }

         $companies_not_found[] = $query;
     }
}
```

Comment: This could be done entirely with your SQL statement without all of the extra PHP code (not to mention it would be faster!). Posting your table structure would help us help you write a query to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 0):

Flip your `WHERE` condition around to find things that don't match your existing condition. Like this

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE company_name NOT IN ('bbc', 'yahoo', 'some company') OR contact_position NOT LIKE 'manager'")
```

Comment: I still need access to the companies that were found though - would this not exclude access to those records?

Comment: Do you want both at the same time? If so, what's the purpose of the WHERE? It seems more like you want to get all the rows...

Comment: There are like 400,000 rows. I only want rows where the company name and job position that are submitted by the user are found - however, I also want to display companies that were found on the DB. The code I posted does actually work - I just thought there may be a better way of doing it using SQL.

Comment: There almost definitely is a better way of doing it complete in SQL, but what you're asking isn't really clear. I'm not sure what the result you're looking for *is*. Maybe try clearing up what your end result should be, and editing your question with it?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to switch the logic, as Gareth points out.  Another is to just use `NOT`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM contacts c
WHERE NOT (company_name IN ('bbc', 'yahoo', 'some company') AND
           contact_position LIKE 'manager'
          );
```

A word of caution:  both of these methods exclude `NULL` values.  So, if `company_name` or `contact_position` is `NULL`, then neither method will return the row (`NULL` comparisons return `NULL` which is treated as false).